# Could not find devise-3.5.0 in any of the sources-rails 4, devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I am working on an older app of mine, old means about 6 months. When I went to start it with rails s I got the following message:

Could not find devise-3.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

so I ran bundle install but then got this message:

Could not find devise-3.5.0 in any of the sources

I tried googling this and did not find anything. Any suggestions on how to fix this? In my gem file the devise gem looks like the following:

gem 'devise'

This app was working fine the last time I pulled it out. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked [the RubyGems page](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions) and the version was yanked for some reason, I don't know why.

Comment: Ha, that is funny, I see that as well-any work arounds? Use a different version?

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318682/answering-own-questions-through-the-outcome-of-another-answer

Answer (score 1):

I got it-used gem 'devise', '~> 3.5.6' instead.